# android in app purchase consumable? non consumable? how to check users already paid

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I have a running version with String ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased"; So I can buy a (fake)product.
Now I realized that this is a consumable product. But I need a non consumable. If u use my in app purchase it is a premium upgrade.

1) What do I have to change that the users buy a non consumable product?

2) A second thing is that I want to check, if anybody already bought the premium product. Surly he/she should pay only once. How can I do this?

I searched a lot in boards or at the official Google API. There is a sample "Trivial Drive" from Google too, where I could find the solutions for my problem. But I didn't find the right code.

Here are some snippets of my code:

```
//a button click call this method
public void buyClick() {
     mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,mPurchaseFinishedListener); 
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
      if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {     
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }
}

public void consumeItem() {
    System.out.println("counsumeItem wurde aufgerufen");
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info) {


               if (result.isFailure()) {
                      return;
                 }      
                 else if (info.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {

                    consumeItem();
                    buyButton.setEnabled(false); 
                }   
            }
        };

        IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
               public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {

             if (result.isSuccess()) {               
                  clickButton.setEnabled(true); //hier den Datenbankzugriff reinmachen
             } else {
                  System.out.println("Handle error");   // handle error
             }
          }
        };


        IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
               public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {


                  if (result.isFailure()) {
                  // Handle failure 
                      System.out.println("FAILURE");
                  } else {
                         mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU), mConsumeFinishedListener);
                  }
            }
        };
```

If u need more code or infos, please give me a sign.